# How to reinstall Perl on OS X

Tags: macos, perl, macports, reinstall

I accidentally deleted the `/System/Library/Perl/` folder. Now I am not be able to run any of my projects.

How can I reinstall Perl on OS X?

Comment: How did you "accidentally" do that ? Anyway, just update your system software and you will get the OS X Perl installation back again.

Comment: @yrosen is there a way like "apt-get install perl" on Mac? I don't have the installation disk.

Comment: @PaulR How to update my system? I don't have the installation disk

Comment: See @yrosen's link to a similar question on SuperUser above - you can use Pacifist to extract the relevant packages.

Comment: What version of OS X do you have?

Comment: You could install perl through macports (there is a macports tag in the question). However, depending on which version you need, it may require some more work than the default 'port install', check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942520/how-do-i-upgrade-my-macports-perl-installation

Comment: @lupincho: you don't need to get Perl from MacPorts - it's already installed as part of OS X

Comment: @Paul R: what I meant is that he could also install it through macports if he deleted the built-in version and doesn't have the OS install disk